# nginx:how use alias route different paths

Tags: nginx, alias

i want point `/m/v2/`,And then the random path，for example `apc, tcb` and so on. To `/var/www/app`.But my configuration shows 404

```
location ~* ^/m/v2/([a-z]+)/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @htmlext;
    alias /opt/www/app/;
    index myInterest.html;
    access_log logs/app_v2_access.log main;
} 

location @htmlext { 
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
}
```

Comment: Please give proper example of what you trying to achieve and include your current config so we can help to fix your code.

Comment: it`s configure
```location ~* ^/m/v2/([a-z]+)/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @htmlext;
    alias /opt/www/app/;
    index myInterest.html;
    access_log logs/app_v2_access.log main;
}

location @htmlext {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `alias` with a regular expression `location` you should construct the full path to the file in the `alias` expression. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Using `alias` with `try_files` is challenging. See [this bug report](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) for details.

Your `$uri.html` and `@htmlext` terms seem to be attempting the same thing. In my example, an `if` block is used instead of the `try_files` statement. See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

For example:

```
location ~* ^/m/v2/([a-z]+)/(.*)$ {
    alias /opt/www/app/$2;
    index myInterest.html;
    access_log logs/app_v2_access.log main;

    if (-e $request_filename.html) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
    }
}
```